# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.time.temporal.Temporal

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I'm trying to run my spark scala code on a cluster but it fails on checkpointing with error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/time/temporal/Temporal
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2436)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Class.java:1946)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.getDeclaredSUID(ObjectStreamClass.java:1659)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.access$700(ObjectStreamClass.java:72)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$2.run(ObjectStreamClass.java:480)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$2.run(ObjectStreamClass.java:468)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.<init>(ObjectStreamClass.java:468)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.lookup(ObjectStreamClass.java:365)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeClass(ObjectOutputStream.java:1212)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1119)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1377)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1173)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:440)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph$$anonfun$writeObject$1.apply$mcV$sp(DStreamGraph.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1205)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph.writeObject(DStreamGraph.scala:175)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:988)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1495)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.Checkpoint$$anonfun$serialize$1.apply$mcV$sp(Checkpoint.scala:141)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.Checkpoint$$anonfun$serialize$1.apply(Checkpoint.scala:141)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.Checkpoint$$anonfun$serialize$1.apply(Checkpoint.scala:141)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1251)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.Checkpoint$.serialize(Checkpoint.scala:142)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.validate(StreamingContext.scala:554)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.liftedTree1$1(StreamingContext.scala:601)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.start(StreamingContext.scala:600)
    at SRDLoader$.main(SRDLoader.scala:71)
    at SRDLoader.main(SRDLoader.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:731)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.time.temporal.Temporal
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 67 more
```

At local machine this problem doesn't appear.
Versions (same for local and cluster):
Scala - 2.10.6,
Java - 1.8.0,
Spark - 1.6.0.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: This was added in Java 8 so it appears you are using an older JVM.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. "java -version" says:
`java version "1.8.0_101"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_101-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.101-b13, mixed mode)`

Comment: I don't doubt this is the version you have installed, but it's not the version which produced this error message,

Comment: @Gorini4 your server has multiple version of java?

Comment: Thanks for your help! Java 8 was installed but spark used Java 7 instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java path in Cloudera Manager doesn't affect version of Java used for spark-submit script. You need to override JAVA_HOME on your server anyway. You may check JAVA_HOME by injecting this snippet in your code:

```
println(System.getenv.toString)
```